# Есть ли у fiddle срок истечения?

Tags: обсуждение, вопросы

Если я хочу включить в свой вопрос (или ответ) fiddle, как долго он будет доступен?

Могу ли я быть уверен, что, скажем, через год он все еще будет действовать?

Или все-таки лучше делать и fiddle и полный код в сообщение вставлять?

Answer (score 8):

Лучше вставлять полный код в сообщение, потому что

- Скорее всего ваш fiddle все еще будет доступен через год ([мои старые примеры от 2012 еще действуют сегодня](http://jsfiddle.net/vAMdH/2/)), но в этом никто не может выть увереным.
- Если кто-то хочет копировать ваш код, удобнее просто копировать из сообщения
- Иногда fiddle сайты загружаются медленно, или совсем не загружаются, особенно на мобильных девайсах или на старых браузерах.

Но если пример кода не очень важен (например, моя ссылка выше) и сообщение полностью понятно без него, то не надо вставлять полный код.

Comment: То, что я планирую запостить ради кода и ставится. Так что пример важен. Но вобщем понятно. Спасибо! Делаю так: вот проблема - вот код ее решения - вот fiddle кода, чтобы могли проверить. Если fiddle умрет - код останется :)

Comment: @cyadvert в самом движке есть встроенный fiddle. зачем дублировать на внешнем?

Comment: @PashaPash Встроенный fiddle только для JavaScript/CSS/HTML, так что иногда приходится использовать [SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/), [ideone](http://ideone.com/), и т.д.

Comment: @PeterOlson я перебирал старые сообщения, и очень многие сторонние фиддлы/pastebin-ы были уже мертвы. так что их стоит испольовать только в качестве доп-ссылки :(

Answer (score 4):

Думаю, лучше всего вставлять полный код в сообщение **и** давать ссылку на fiddle.

Полный код поможет читателям понять вопрос, не переходя по дополнительным ссылкам. Кроме того, он гарантированно будет доступен через любое время.

Fiddle пригодится тем, кто хочет поэкспериментировать с кодом, например в поисках решения.

Answer (score 2):

Зарегистрировавшись на сайтах fiddle, Вы сможете контролировать свои fiddle, в частности срок их хранения.
Появление встроенного fiddle по `css/js/html` также частично решило проблему, будем надеяться, что в будущем его расширят и до иных языков.